# Was there the best poker player on board of DS9?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Inspired by the last question about TNG ( [Who's the best poker player?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8162/whos-the-best-poker-player)  ), is there enough information on who the best poker player is on DS9?

Comment: May I ask why the down votes please?

Comment: This seems like a trivia question. See: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/what-are-our-boundaries (the issue is still open to debate though)

Comment: @NHL - I thought that trivia were questions from Wiki or IMDB... the answer here wasn't on either based on what I see.

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with Sci Fi or Fantasy.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: DS9 is Sci-Fi, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Wikis Poker is not Sci-Fi. The question has nothing actually to do with SciFi or Fantasy itself. There was another question that is now deleted that was about Clark Kent and why he was always pining over Lana Lang. The question had SciFi characters, but the question itself had nothing to do with the SciFi aspects of the Superman universe. It was closed as being off topic and deleted. As should this and the other poker question.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Since the beginning of the site, we've accepted questions that were either about an SFnal aspect of a work or about a non-SFnal aspect of an SF work. The Superman question you refer to was closed as “non-constructive” (because it was essentially asking to read a fictional character's mind with no help from the author), not as off-topic. If you want to start a major shift in the topic of the site, raise the issue on meta first.

Comment: @HNL [Non-trivial trivia is what the site is all about](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190/what-is-scifi-ses-elevator-pitch/212#212).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seem to recall that Jadzia Dax was (saw it on some poker article, let me try and find a relevant quote).

UPDATE: found one better - an actual dialogue from DS9 episode "Paradise":

From: http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/435.txt

> DEEP SPACE: "Paradise" - REV. 12/08/93 - ACT TWO 14-16.
>                               ACT TWO
>   ...
>
> 2    INT. OPS
>
> KIRA and DAX at their stations.  N.D. Supernumeraries as needed.  Kira is picking up a message on her panel.
>
> KIRA : Do you know an Admiral Mitsuya...
>
> DAX : Best poker player in the fleet.
>     Next to me.

Comment: Thank you... One nitpick...that's quite a claim! Is there anything other than self-boasting to back it up in-Universe?

Comment: @user3885 We did see her kicking some Ferengi butt in that card game they frequently played at Quark's.

Comment: The best poker player on DS9 doesn't have to be "in the fleet".

Comment: @Keen: “that card game” — specifically, Tongo.