# How did Starfleet Academy deal with Betazoids and other telepaths?

Tags: star-trek

Since Betazoids are telepathic, it would seem they would have a prohibitive advantage in an academic setting. How did Starfleet Academy deal with Betazoids and other telepaths in trying to keep everyone on a level playing field?

Comment: In addition to using computers and telepathy-immune species, I wonder if they use **meta-telepathy**: telepaths who can detect when another telepath is using telepathy. Just like human teachers can catch a human student copying from somebody else, maybe telepathic teachers can catch a telepathic student by "watching" (hearing?) the student's telepathy.

Comment: This does raise a more general question: how are telepathic students tested when they're in school? Of course, the answer might be "it's a utopia and nobody would cheat" anyway.

Comment: @KevinWorkman - Which raises an even more general question of why Betazed isn't one of the most technologically advanced races because they would be able to steal secrets quite easily from just about everyone else.

Comment: Do we know that they're **not** one of the most technologically advanced species? I guess it depends on how you define "advanced" - maybe they focused on exploring **inwardly** instead of outwardly, and they're one of the most emotionally/introspectively advanced species? Woah dude.

Comment: A lot of the telepaths only got the current active thoughts when simply in proximity with others, not full access to all memory, and processing.  If you only get active thoughts, then you could write a testing algorithm to generate questions, instead of having a fixed test.  So each individual gets a unique question set.  That combined with randomized ordering and so on, might help remove advantage.

Comment: Along the same lines, did Betazoids cheat at poker? Deanna could at least sense when you are bluffing, or when you had a great hand. Full blooded Betazoids could presumably read your mind and know precisely  what cards you were holding.

Comment: @Sareesataka - This question has actually been raised before. Imagine playing poker with an empath who can detect a bluff, a guy with a VISOR that can see the other side of cards, and a sophisticated android capable of stacking the deck & counting every card. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6515/54605

Comment: @Sareesataka - [Why would Troi be allowed to play poker?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6515/why-would-troi-be-allowed-to-play-poker?lq=1)

Comment: @Valorum - I posted that link already in my previous comment. Finally beat you at something for once. :-p

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tests can be administered by computer. We see an example of this in Star Trek IV with the "[memory test](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Memory_test)" that Spock takes. Since Betazeds can't scan computers, this would be an effective way of testing them as long as they weren't in the vicinity of other testees.

I would assume that any live test where a telepathic alien was involved would require them to operate on the [honour system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor_system), simply *asking them* not to use their abilities to subvert the purpose of the test.

> **Capt. Picard:** ***The first duty of every Starfleet officer is to the truth**, whether it's scientific truth or historical truth or personal
> truth! It is the guiding principle on which Starfleet is based. And if
> you can't find it within yourself to stand up and tell the truth about
> what happened, you don't deserve to wear that uniform!*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: The First Duty](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_First_Duty_(episode))</sup></sub>

There's also the possibility that in addition to computerised testing, they would also use holodeck simulations like the [Bridge Officer's test](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bridge_Officer%27s_Test)  administered to Deanna Troi in [TNG: Thine Own Self](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Thine_Own_Self_(episode)) (Mrs Troi confirms in [TNG: Manhunt](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Manhunt_(episode)) that she can't read holograms).

In extreme cases, they might also use aliens who're [resistant to telepathy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Telepathy). Ferengis and Cardassians are probably out, but Vulcan masters are known to have this skill so there are almost certainly others that can be used.

Comment: "holodeck simul" ... click here to pay $19.99 and read the rest of this answer.

Comment: I suppose this begs the question, how far is a telepath's range? Maybe it would be easier to give everyone Magneto helmets.

Comment: @iMerchant - They can do ship-to-ship at least. I don't think there's evidence of interstellar communication. Worthy of its own question, perhaps

Comment: Ship to ship seems only to be a vague sense, or with another telepath actively projecting information.

Comment: @ewanm89 Certainly true for Deanna, but she isn't a full Betazoid after all....

Comment: @ewanm89 - [Tam Elbrun](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Tam_Elbrun) seems much more capable of intership communication

Comment: @iMerchant Actually, it sounds like it raises the question.  "Begging the question" is really something else altogether, the logical fallacy of assuming as fact the very thing one is thus "proving" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question.

Comment: @MontyHarder - I think you'll find that while it used to mean only that, dictionaries and thesauri now reflect the *modern usage* as well. Unless you subscribe to the idea that dictionaries should be used to pin language to the page like a butterfly, trapped eternally and unchanging.

Comment: @MontyHarder - Can I PLEASE ask that question? Pretty please?? I really want to. I'm begging you.

Comment: @MontyHarder, from your link -- The term "begging the question", as this is usually phrased, originated in the 16th century as a mistranslation of the Latin petitio principii, which actually translates as "assuming the initial point".[2] In modern vernacular usage, "to beg the question" is sometimes used to mean "to invite the question" (as in "This begs the question of whether...") or "to dodge a question".[2] These usages are often criticized as being mistaken.[3] -- So he used the vernacular usage and was told he was mistaken ;)

Comment: Why use something as complicated as a computer?  A simple pen and paper would be similarly immune—just seat the candidate sufficiently far from any others sitting the same examination.

Comment: @eggyal - Pen and paper? In the future only weirdos and bohemians use those.

Comment: Perhaps.  Then again, for examination purposes they do have the benefit of being tamper proof.